# IF OR statement var = true, then write document

Tags: javascript, if-statement, var

Javascript really isn't my forte, so just seeking some help to get this issue resolved.

I need to engage a smooth scrolling script targeted at IE & Chrome. I know that doing a UserAgent check these days is pretty much futile, and my need doesn't fit the mold of doing browser feature detection. Nor can I target IE gte 10 with a conditional comment, so I'm left trying to do some browser hacks.

I found the browserhacks.com resource that provides variables to target specific versions or version ranges of browsers, so that i can create a blanket logic applied towards these browsers.

So at the immediate time, I'm using these:

For Chrome

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
```

For IE

```
var isIE = document.all && window.XMLHttpRequest;
var isIE = document.body.style.msTouchAction !== undefined;
```

I'm presuming I need to just create an "IF" "OR" statement to cover all of these, to then engage:

```
document.write('<script src="js/smooth-scrolling.js"><\/script>');
```

This is what I had:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
    var isIE = document.all && window.XMLHttpRequest;
    var isIE = document.body.style.msTouchAction !== undefined;
    document.write('<script src="js/smooth-scrolling.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

This works for applying the smooth scrolling to IE & Chrome, but it is also applying it to Firefox, and I don't want that since Firefox already has very smooth native scrolling, and the script actually degrades scrolling performance in Firefox a little.

Then I tried (feeble attempt I'm sure):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore) {
        document.write('<script src="js/smooth-scrolling.js"><\/script>')
    }

    if (var isIE = document.all && window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        document.write('<script src="js/smooth-scrolling.js"><\/script>')
    }

    if (var isIE = document.body.style.msTouchAction !== undefined) {
        document.write('<script src="js/smooth-scrolling.js"><\/script>')
    }
</script>
```

...and that just breaks everything. Just trying to get the script to engage without hitting every browser.

Comment: You're asking us how to write an `if` statement. Shows no research effort.

Comment: so what have you tried?

Comment: I imagine I just got my first negative feedback because you think this is too simple a question to ask?

Comment: @SnakeFast: No because you didn't answer the question. Whatever the question is.

Comment: Fair enough. I probably should have posted it as a comment. (:

Comment: @SnakeFast: Probably :)

Comment: Added some additional notes for what I had that was "partially" working, but was being applied to all browsers, and then my attempt at IF statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't use document.write(); You have to create a new script element and add it the DOM.

```
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
if(isChrome){
  var s=document.createElement('script');
  s.src='source_to-Your_JS.js';
  document.head.appendChild(s);
}
```

Comment: this did the trick exactly as needed, thanks for providing a straight-forward actionable answer without busting my cojones for not being familiar with the language